# iframe resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery plugin: http://plugins.jquery.it/project/jquery-iframe-resizer

However it seems to be working only within the same domain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the `iframe` can't access its contents on other domains because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Note too the [plugin page says](http://code.google.com/p/sroucheray-js/wiki/JqueryIframeResizer)...

> ATTENTION : due to same origin policy this plugin won't work with iframes not coming from the same domain as the calling page

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your 'question' is not at all in the form of a question, and hence, there is really nothing to answer..

Secondly, if you want to get iframe resizing to work across domains, then take a look at easyXDM, you can find an example [here](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this library instead to get around the cross domain issue.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer